# How do I dynamically add click event handlers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/namanyayg/KtmHb/)

There's a simple for loop, can anyone explain to me why isn't it working?

Here's the code (it's there in the fiddle too)

JS -

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i, anchor; anchor = anchors[i]; i++) {
    console.log('looping');
anchor.addEventListener("click", setNavigation, false);
}​
```

HTML -

```
​<a href="#"></a>
<a​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ href="lol"></a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Please fix your title and fiddle.

Comment: Your Fiddle lacks any anchors, so doesn't do anything and doesn't reproduce your problem (which is the whole purpose of supplying a demo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `i` to the value `0`. Use `for (var i=0, …`.

Btw, usually you check for `i` to be smaller than the `length` of the iterated collection instead of looking for truthy values in the loop-condition. Then you also wouldn't need that additional variable `anchor`:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++) {
    console.log('looping');
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", setNavigation, false);
}​
```

Comment: Except, `anchors.length` is a value that can change. So, `for (var i=0, j=anchors.length; i < j; i++)...`.

Comment: Doesn't happen when adding event listeners. Of course, if you have a *live* `NodeList` *and* manipulate them during the loop, you have to watch out.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName "Note: While the W3C specification says elements is a NodeList, this method returns a HTMLCollection both in Gecko and Internet Explorer. Opera returns a NodeList, but with a namedItem method implemented, which makes it similar to a HTMLCollection. As of January 2012, only in WebKit browsers is the returned value a pure NodeList."